# Django can't find my template directory even though it's configured in settings?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use an HTML template for django mail module. MY current issue is that I'm getting this error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist
```

when I try to render HTML inside my app called `users`:

```
html = render_to_string('email/email_confirm.html', context)
```

Here is my folder layout, my app is called users, my project settings live in `/core`. My templates are located in BASE_DIR.

[image]

Here is my templates code in settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

How can I get Django to properly find the templates folder? I have all my apps hooked up and data is working fine. This is strictly a templates path issue.

EDIT:
I have kept my `APP_DIRS` = True and moved the templates/email folder inside the users application folder.

Still django is not finding the template?

Here is the View.py in question:

```
class CustomUserCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                # GENERATE EMAIL CONFIRMATION TOKEN
                user_data = serializer.data
                user = User.objects.get(email=user_data['email'])

                token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token

                # GENERATE EMAIL CONFIRMATION TEMPLATE
                current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
                relative_link = reverse('users:email-verify')


                # CHANGE TO HTTPS in PRODUCTION
                absurl = 'http://'+current_site+relative_link+"?token="+str(token)
                email_body = 'Hi '+ user.username+', Please use link below to verify your email \n' + absurl

                context = {
                    'name': user.first_name,
                }
                html = render_to_string('email/email_confirm.html', context)
                text = render_to_string(email_body, context)


                data = {'to_email':user.email,
                        'email_subject': 'Verify your email',
                        'email_body':email_body,
                        'message':text,
                        'html_message':html
                }


                Util.send_email(data)

                return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

EDIT 2:
First I tried doing this:

```
template = get_template('email/email_confirm.html', { 'name': user.first_name})
```

I got `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` as an error for the above.

Then I switched it around doing this:

```
absurl = 'http://'+current_site+relative_link+"?token="+str(token)
email_body = 'Hi '+ user.username+', Please use link below to verify your email \n' + absurl

context = {
    'name': user.first_name,
}

template = get_template('email/email_confirm.html')

email = render_to_string(template, context)


data = {'to_email':user.email,
        'email_subject': 'Verify your email',
        'email_body':email_body,
        'html_message':email
}


Util.send_email(data)
```

Which lead to this error:

```
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'Template'
```

final edit:

```
                data = {'to_email':user.email,
                        'email_subject': 'Please Verify Your Email',
                        'email_body':email_body,
                        'html_message':html
                }
```

Comment: On the yellow debug screen it should show you the paths that it has looked in, have you got that? That should give you a clue as to what your current settings are doing any how you might be able to fix it.

Comment: Which yellow debug screen?

Comment: Django's error screen when you're in debug mode. It's a yellow colour and has plenty of debugging info.

Comment: `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /home/user/app/backend/templates/Hi user, Please use link below to verify your email `

It doesn't seem its finding the right template?

Comment: Please see my new update,  I have added my view.py

Comment: Try `from django.template.loader import get_template` and call `get_template('email/email_confirm.html')` Does this return an error? If not pass it you `render_to_string`

Comment: which django version do you have

Comment: `Django==3.1.4`

Comment: @PacketLoss, just tried doing what you mentioned. I didn't get any template errors when trying your method, but it did lead to some other issues. Why wouldn't render_to_string method work for me ?

Comment: What were the other errors, did it render as intended?

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Please provide the full traceback for the error in your second edit

Comment: `template = get_template('email/email_confirm.html')` will [return a Template object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.get_template), but render_to_string expects a string as the first argument (thats why you get the TypeError). Maybe there is some access issue for the django process to get the `email_confirm.html` file inside the `templates/email` folder. More stack trace on the error, would help

Comment: Try entering the absolute path in the `DIRS`

Comment: is it possible for you to  add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) @woof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the arguments to `render_to_string` are a path to a template, and a context dictionary. Fundamentally the issue is ensuring you are passing a template path to `render_to_string` every time you call it.

In your first post, the issue is not with the line that you've highlighted
(`html = render_to_string('email/email_confirm.html', context)`), that line is actually totally fine and not the source of your errors. Rather the following line where the first argument to `render_to_string` is a string of the email body: `text = render_to_string(email_body, context)`. There is no rendering to be done here since `email_body` is already a string of content. You can delete that line entirely and use `email_body` instead of `text` elsewhere in your code.

Alternatively you can create a new template for the text body of the email (maybe `email/email_confirm.txt`) and render that instead of using string concatenation to create `email_body`.

In the edits, this sequence is problematic:

```
                template = get_template('email/email_confirm.html')
            
                email = render_to_string(template, context)
```

since `render_to_string` takes a path to a template, not the template itself. The fact that `get_template` worked here is just an illustration that your template settings are working fine and that `email = render_to_string('email/email_confirm.html', context)` was never the issue in the first place and was a bit of a red herring. Once you solve the issue with the `text = render_to_string(email_body, context)` line the original code to create the `html` variable is fine.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, can I check my new edit to see my send email data dictionary. Would this be the correct way to setting up the template? Using `html_message` as the dict key?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on how `Util.send_email` works. Can you share the source for that? Here is the django documentation for adding an html content type to your email: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types

Answer (score 2):

did you tried **EmailMultiAlternatives** ?

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

def sendMail():
    ctx = {
        #your context here..
    }

    html_content = render_to_string('path/to_email.html', context=ctx)
    text_content = strip_tags(html_content)

    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject= "Activate your Account",
        body=text_content,
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        to=[to_email]
    )
    email.attach_alternative(html_content,"text/html")
    res = email.send()
```